# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not a mapping

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to concatenate two dictionaries, and I am getting this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[3], line 5
      3 dict_list = [{"a":1}, None, {"b":2}]
      4 n = len(dict_list)
----> 5 [{"a": 1, "b": 2, **dict_list[idx]} for idx in range(n)]

Cell In[3], line 5
      3 dict_list = [{"a":1}, None, {"b":2}]
      4 n = len(dict_list)
----> 5 [{"a": 1, "b": 2, **dict_list[idx]} for idx in range(n)]

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not a mapping
```

This is the code:

```
import random
# list of dictionaries:
dict_list = [{"a":1}, None, {"b":2}]
n = len(dict_list)
[{"a": 1, "b": 2, **dict_list[idx]} for idx in range(n)]
```

What is wrong? Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]! Also, what is the question you're asking? At the moment, there is none...

Answer (score 0):

When concatenating two dictionaries, if one of them is None, it will cause problems

These will work:

```
dict_var = {"b": 2}
print({"a": 1, **dict_var})
dict_var = {"b": 2}
print({"a": 1} | dict_var)
```

But these will result in error

```
dict_var = None
print({"a": 1, **dict_var})
dict_var = None
print({"a": 1} | dict_var)
```

What you can do is check if it is none before hand:

```
dict_var = None
print({"a": 1, **(dict_var if dict_var is not None else {})})
```